# MySQL query with placeholder does not work

Tags: php, mysql, database

I defined below function. This function supposed to work with different number of values for one mySQL query.

```
function queryMysql($query, $type, $arr)
{
    global $connection; // this is mysql connection

    $count = count($arr);
    $val = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
        $val[] = $arr[$i];
    }

    $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);

    switch ($count) {
        case 1:
            $stmt->bind_param($type, $val[0]);
            break;
        case 2:
            $stmt->bind_param($type, $val[0], $val[1]);
            break;
        case 3:
            $stmt->bind_param($type, $val[0], $val[1], $val[2]);
            break;
    }

    $stmt->execute();

    printf("%d Row affected.\n", $stmt->num_rows);

    // rest of function
}
```

and I called it like below:

```
$result = queryMysql("SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE my_value=?", 's', array('user'));
```

and this keeps showing me:

```
0 Row affected.
```

What am I doing wrong? I read documentation on php.net and related question on stackoverflow but I couldn't find the problem. Also I'm sure the database contains some rows which match this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to store the result before getting row count.

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
printf("%d Row affected.\n", $stmt->num_rows);
```

**[mysqli_stmt::$num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)**