# Can't find exact record with simple SQL Query. (PHP MySQLi)

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm having a problem finding specific records in my new program for the company. This is a ridiculously simple SQL query that I just can't get passed for the life of me.

Can anyone see a problem?

```
public function loadByKey($partNumber, $customerNumber, $rev){
    $query = 'SELECT *'
            .' FROM '.$this->myTableName
            .' WHERE PartNumber = ?'
            .' AND CustomerNumber = ?'
            .' AND Rev = ?';

    $conn = (new DBConnector)->connect();

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    //var_dump($statement);
    //var_dump($query);
    //var_dump($conn);
    $statement->bind_param('sis', $partNumber, $customerNumber, $rev);
    $result = $statement->execute();
    //var_dump($result);
    //var_dump($statement);
    //var_dump($customerNumber);
    //var_dump($rev);

    if ($statement->num_rows == 1) {
    // output data of each row
        $this->Properties = $statement->fetch_assoc();
        var_dump($this->Properties);
        $conn->close();
        return true;
    } else {
        $this->Properties = [];
        $conn->close();
        return false;
    }  

}
```

Comment: And... what is wrong?

Comment: Removing your code from the equation, does the SQL work? What's the error?

Comment: Check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after your execute. Also check to see if num_rows actually equals 1, or if it's more or less rows.

Comment: Missing [`mysqli_stmt_store_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php)?

Comment: Im sending data I know is in my DB, cant use actual part numbers for fear of NDA breaking, But I've input exactly what I need and I can find any results. In my PartCollection object I have "like" statements that work but exact matches always fail

Comment: I should probably point out that there are no errors, but this query never works no matter the parameters. It always returns 0 rows even when I hard code the data

Comment: `I have "like" statements that work but exact matches always fail` and `when I hard code the data`, well my first instinct says that you have some issue in your data such as spaces in your part numbers in the actual database.  Because if `like $partnumber.%` matches and `= $partnumber` doesn't then you must have something in there you are not matching.  And even an extra space at the end can cause that to happen.

Comment: further more `I should probably point out that there are no errors` this all says there is some issue in the data stored in the Database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL query with placeholder does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453153/mysql-query-with-placeholder-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1):

Missing mysqli_stmt_store_result? – ficuscr
After delving into this and reading my older code this is the answer:

```
public function loadByKey($partNumber, $customerNumber, $rev){
    $query = 'SELECT *'
            .' FROM '.$this->myTableName
            .' WHERE PartNumber = ?'
            .' AND CustomerNumber = ?'
            .' AND Rev = ?';

    $conn = (new DBConnector)->connect();

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    //var_dump($statement);
    //var_dump($query);
    //var_dump($conn);
    $statement->bind_param('sis', $partNumber, $customerNumber, $rev);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->get_result();
    var_dump($result);
    //var_dump($statement);
    //var_dump($customerNumber);
    //var_dump($rev);

    if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
    // output data of each row
        $this->Properties = $result->fetch_assoc();
        var_dump($this->Properties);
        $conn->close();
        return true;
    } else {
        $this->Properties = [];
        $conn->close();
        return false;
    }  

}
```